# PHP AJAX multi Form not inserting to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The code works normal but when i click submit it doesn't insert to database and doesn't return any sql error.
here is my index code:

```html
<?php
require_once("functions/functions.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$query ="SELECT * FROM country";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
error_reporting();
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Kickoff360 - Add Match Fixtures</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/bootstrap.min.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css" >
  <script src="/style/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/style/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
 <body>

  <div class="container"><h3>Add Match Fixtures</h3>
   <div class="omenu">P/S: Use the <b>Add More</b> button to add more input fields, <b>X</b> to remove input fields</div>
   <br />

   <div class="form-group">
    <form name="add_team" class="form-inline" id="add_team">
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" id="fieldset">
       <tr class="danger">
        <td width="10%" class="trH"><span>LEAGUE</span></td>
        <td width="60%" class="trH"><span>HOME & AWAY TEAMS</span></td>
        <td width="3%" class="trH"><span>DATE</span></td>
        <td width="3%" class="trH"><span>TIME</span></td> </tr></thead>
       <tr id="row1"><td width="10%">
        <select name="league[]" class="form-control" onChange="getState(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select League</option>
        <?php foreach($results as $country) { ?><option id="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["country_name"]; ?></option>
       <?php } ?></select></td><td width="60%">
       <select class="form-control" name="home[]" id="home1" class="select"><option value="">HOME TEAM</option></select>
        <span class="btn btn-danger">VS</span>
       <select class="form-control" name="away[]" id="away1" class="select"><option value="">AWAY TEAM</option></select>
      </td><td width="3%"><input type="date" name="date[]" class="form-control"></td> <td width="3%"><input type="time" name="time[]" class="form-control"></td>
 <td width="20%"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"  style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: -1;">Add</button><span></span><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="display:inline-block;" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
 </table>

     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

  var i=1;
  function getState(val) {
   var home = $("#home"+i+"");
   var away = $("#away"+i+"");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "name.php",
    data: 'country_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
     $(home).html(data).serialize();
     $(away).html(data).serialize();
    }
    });
   }
    function selectCountry(val) {
    $("#search-box").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
    }

$(document).ready(function (){


 $('#add').click(function(){
  i++;
  var home = $("#home"+i+"");
  var away = $("#away"+i+"");
  $(fieldset).append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td width="10%"><select name="country" class="form-control" onChange="getState(this.value);"><option value="">Select Country</option><?php foreach($results as $country) { ?><option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["country_name"]; ?></option><?php } ?></select></td><td width="50%"><select name="home[]" id="home'+i+'" class="form-control"><option value="">HOME TEAM</option></select> <span class="btn btn-danger">VS</span>  <select name="away[]" id="away'+i+'" class="form-control"><option value="">AWAY TEAM</option></select></td><td width="3%"><input type="date" class="form-control"></td> <td width="3%"><input type="time" class="form-control"></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
 });

 $('#submit').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"name.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:$('#add_team').serialize(),
   success:function(data)
   {
    alert(data);
    //$('#add_team')[0].reset();


   }
  });
 });

});
</script>
```

This is my name.php

```html
<?php
require_once('C:\wamp645\www\fixtures\functions\functions.php');

$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["country_id"])) {
 $query = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE countryID = '" . $_POST["country_id"] . "'";
 $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
 <option value="">SELECT TEAM</option>
<?php
 foreach($results as $state) {
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $state["name"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
 }
}
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "k_fixtures");
$number = count($_POST["home"]);
if($number >= 0)
{
 for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
 {
  $league = $_POST['league'][$i];
  $home = escapeStr($_POST["home"][$i]);
  $away = escapeStr($_POST["away"][$i]);
  $date = escapeStr($_POST['date'][$i]);
  $time = escapeStr($_POST['time'][$i]);

$error = array();
  if(empty($league)) {
 $error = "This field cannot be blank";
}
  if(empty($home)) {
   $error = "This field cannot be blank";
  }
  if(empty($away)) {
   $error = "This field cannot be blank";
  }
  if(empty($date)) {
   $error = "This field cannot be blank";
  }
  if(empty($time)) {
   $error = "This field cannot be blank";
  }
   $sql = "INSERT INTO k_fixtures SET
   league = '$league',
   team1 = '$home',
   team2 = '$away',
   dates = '$date',
   times = '$time'
   ";
   $sql2 = querySql($sql); or die(mysqli_error($connect));
}
 }
 if($sql2) {
 echo "Data Inserted";
}
else
{
 echo "Data not Inserted";
}
```

Note: The functions, querySql() has been declared already at functions.php
the code stores to my database while i was using text inputs until i recently added the select option.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is too much code which is not involved in your question.

Comment: The INSERT statement has a wrong syntax. [See the Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

Comment: sidenote: til now you are still inserting even when there was an error!

Comment: Security side note: escape all user input, always. Even select/radio/checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO k_fixtures (league,team1,team2,dates,times)
VALUES ('$league','$home','$away','$date','$time')";
```

I think this is the insert youre looking for

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement is correct but put the insert into a condition like :-

```
if($error == ''){
     $sql = "INSERT INTO k_fixtures SET
     league = '$league',
     team1 = '$home',
     team2 = '$away',
     dates = '$date',
     times = '$time'";

     $sql2 = querySql($sql); or die(mysqli_error($connect));
     if($sql2) {
         echo "Data Inserted";
     }
     else{
         echo "Data not Inserted";
     }
  }
```